# Pinterest - Why are my icons not displaying full images?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I'm using the Pin it button on a site, but when you use it it only displays a cut off icon of the image. Whereas using the button anywhere else, it will display the full size image.

I'm digged through my code, but can't find a solution.

Can anyone help? It doesn't seem to work with either the Pin it button, or the browser extension.

Here's a link to the site:

http://www.slurp.co.uk/red-wine/chilean-red-wine/18173-casillero-del-diablo-cabernet-sauvignon-2010/

Code:

```
<iframe src="http://d3io1k5o0zdpqr.cloudfront.net/pinit.html?url=http://www.slurp.co.uk/red-wine/chilean-red-wine/18173-casillero-del-diablo-cabernet-sauvignon-2010/&amp;media=http://www.slurp.co.uk/images/products/small/18173.jpg&amp;layout=horizontal" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; width: 90px; height: 20px; "></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add code so folks can better help you out...

Comment: Rookie error, sorry. Code has now been added as well as a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to style that IFRAME to have a width and height.  These are the settings:

```
+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Orientation-of-Count | Width | Height |
+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Horizontal           | 90px  | 20px   |
| Vertical             | 43px  | 58px   |
| None                 | 43px  | 20px   |
+----------------------+-------+--------+
```

Couple other things that you did not ask about, but might want to know:

1. You need not insert the IFRAME and then use pinit.js.    The function of the pinit.js code is to  replace specially-marked ANCHOR (`A`) tags in your document with the IFRAME tags pointed at the pinterest CDN (cloudfront.net).  If you are inserting IFRAMEs with the appropriate `src` attribute, then you don't need pinit.js.
2. the query params on the `src` attribute of that IFRAME need to be encoded.  In particular, the colon and slashes in the `url` and `media` params need to be uri-encoded. In Javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent()` to accomplish this.  I've found that pinterest is sort of picky about the  format of the URLs, and will fail silently if you get something wrong. If you use an media URL that includes spaces or parens, I believe it will fail, even though these are legal characters for HTTP URIs. Likewise for the page URL.
3. In case you were wondering:  I don't believe you can eliminate the use of the IFRAME.  I believe pinterest may be looking at the REFERRER, and it may silently reject any pin/create/button requests that have not been referred by cloudfront.net.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here:

http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder

We've launched a new set of buttons and widgets that should help.